# Using a regex to update the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query where I want that in one column which has special characters should be replaced by underscore.

I have something like this:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM TABLE
WHERE Col1 like '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
```

which works, I just want the special characters to be replaced by underscore and only one underscore.

Like if I have this

```
Page$%^65*&^^^
```

it should be `Page_65` because after 65 there is no `alphanumeric` or `number`. Any ideas?

Comment: SQL Server does not support REGEX, it only supports basic patten matching; and it does not support pattern replacement at all. Personally, if you can, I would suggest looking up some CLR functions to achieve this.

Comment: what is CLR functions?

Comment: [Create CLR Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: please give us a testable example to achieve this task done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. The below is for the example you have provided.

```
select (REGEXP_SUBSTR(regexp_replace('Page$%^65*&^^^','[^a-z_A-Z_0-9 ]'), '[[:alpha:]]+')
      ||'_'||
      REGEXP_SUBSTR(regexp_replace('Page$%^65*&^^^','[^a-z_A-Z_0-9 ]'), '[^[:alpha:]]+.*')) as col1 from dual;
```

Comment: is dual from oracle?